# opening a radwindow from a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How to open a radwindow on the click event of a Imagebutton within a user control? 
Moreover i have used the same code in aspx page and it works fine.

car.ascx

code behind car.ascx.cs

```
protected void btnCarLogo_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  carurl="https://www.google.co.in/"

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popCarWindow", "window.radopen('" + carurl + "', 'CarDetails');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has *VisibleOnPageLoad* property. If you set it to *true*, window will be visible after postback.

**Examples:**

*Show window*

```
myRadWindow.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
```

*Hide window*

```
myRadWindow.VisibleOnPageLoad = false;
```

Comment: +1 but Make sure to set `EnableViewState="false"` to prevent the RadWindow from opening after AJAX events if you aren't able to set `VisibleOnPageLoad="false"` as soon as you close the window

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/opening-radwindow-from-the-server.aspx and see that the parameters are Page and not this (i.e. UserCOntrol).

Here is on working with JS functio nnames in user controls: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/general/using-dynamic-unique-names-for-javascript-functions.aspx

And, if you are going to have more than one manager on the page: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radwindow-troubleshooting-wrong-window-opened.html.

Answer (score 0):

That way probably you get errors stating that the window is null

Try it like this:
Code behind:

```
string script = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>Sys.Application.add_load(ShowWindow);</script>";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showWindow", script);
```

Then on your aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function ShowWindow()   
    {   
        var oWnd = window.radopen('https://www.google.co.in/', 'window1');   
    }       
</script>
```